# Count innerText lines, and remove a few lines using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript that I have been working on. Part of the script copies some text from a website using innerText. I want to be able to count the amount of lines in the innerText attribute, and then delete a number of lines.

What would be the best approach for me to take on this? Should I put the contents of innerText an array, and then remove the lines I don't want? Or is there another approach that I should take?

Comment: the best approach would be for you to create a concrete example using jsfiddle.net or a similar tool.  It should also include your attempt at solving the problem on your own, at which point people will be much more inclined to help you after knowing what you tried.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by lines? it could be 1 long line, but visually word wrapped into 8 lines. Or could it be line separated using <br> tags?

Comment: heads up: `elm.innerText` is not consistent between browsers.

Comment: Please provide a **[Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** to go along with your question, we can only imagine so much, a code snippet is always recommended.

Comment: Don't use `innerText`, it's not standard and doesn't exist in FireFox. Use `textContent` instead.

Comment: To do what you want, use `.split('\n')` to split the string into an array of lines. Then you can remove elements from the array, and combine them back with `.join('\n')`.